# Can an ASP.NET application access the standard ASP.NET UserId guid without access to the parent applications provider?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

I have written a application which resides in a subdirectory of the parent, or root application.

The root application uses a custom membership provider, but all the code for it is in the App_Code directory, and it's compiled deep into the Temp files for ASP.NET.

Therefore, it complains that it's missing a reference to the provider when I do:

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

I need to get the UserId guid for shoving into some database table for tracking.  Is there any other way to get at this key from a child application?  Or is there a way to make a child application load DLLs from the parents reference directories?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is moving your custom membership provider into separate class library (DLL) project. Then, you'll be able to access it both from the root and child websites.

Comment: Yeah, but the team that wrote that doesn't want to...  Thanks though!